# Validation for the count of has_many relationship in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have been through other questions, but the scenario is little different here:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :documents, as: :attachable

  validate :validate_no_of_documents

  private
  def validate_no_of_documents
    errors.add(:documents, "count shouldn't be more than 2") if self.documents.size > 2
  end
end


class Document < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true

  validates_associated :attachable
end
```

Now, consider `User.find(2)` that already has two documents, so doing the following:

```
user.documents << Document.new(file: File.open('image.jpg', 'rb'))
```

This successfully creates the document, and doesn't validate the attachable: `User`. After the document is created in the database, both `user` & `Document.last` are invalid, but of what use, they have been created now.

I'm trying to create a `Document` object on the run time, and that may be causing it, but for that purpose, I'm using `size` instead of `count` in my validation.

Comment: if you make `if self.documents.size > 2` to `if self.documents.size > 1`, it will stop creating third document for the same user. The validate method for user is triggered before `Document` is created

Comment: Have you tried putting `validates_associated :user` in `document.rb`?

Comment: @Pavan `validates_associated :user` wont' work in `Document` for polymorphic `attachable'. `user` will be undefined.

Comment: @Arslan : hey, did you manage to get any good solution for this?

Comment: @kiddorails: Yes, I got one, and have posted it as an answer.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks! I will go through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inverse_of` to rescue here again.

```
user = User.find(1) # This user has already 2 associated documents.
```

Doing `user.documents << Document.new(file: file)` won't change the count for the associated documents of a user unless a document is actually created, and since the count will remain 2 while creating a 3rd document, so Rails won't stop you creating a third document associated with the user, killing the very purpose of putting the validation.

So following is what I did:

```
# In User model
has_many :documents, as: :attachable, inverse_of: :attachable

# In Document model
belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true, inverse_of: :attachments
```

Related article to read: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through

Answer (score 1):

You can use a standard validation for this, rather than a custom one:

```
validates :documents, length: { maximum: 2 }
```

You could always wrap this in a transaction, though I'm a little surprised it isn't properly rolling back the Document save if it doesn't end up being valid.